# calling a event handler within another event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

Here is the short sample code:

```
private void txtbox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e); //can I call button1 event handler?
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(txtbox1.Text);
}
```

I wonder if it would be okay to code in the above way?

Comment: You could but do you really want to? Instead you could factor out the common code and delegate from the handlers. I think it a lot cleaner. Sorry didn't see that exact answer below - do that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that - although the code you provide can't be compiled. It should look like this:

```
private void txtbox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click(sender, e);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(txtbox1.Text);
}
```

But for best practice and code readability, you're probably better off doing this, especially as you are not making use of `sender` and `e`:

```
private void txtbox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMessageBox();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMessageBox();
}

private void ShowMessageBox()
{
    MessageBox.Show(txtbox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: hmm, are `sender` and `e` used in both event handlers referencing the same thing?

Comment: @woodykiddy no - the sender for txtbox1_DoubleClick is txtbox1 and the sender for button1_Click will be button1 if the event handlers have been wired as standard using the Windows Form Designer

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do that; an event handler is just another method.

However it might be worth creating a new method that shows the message box, and having both Click event handlers call that:

```
private void txtbox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowTextboxMessage();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowTextboxMessage();
}

private void ShowTextboxMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show(txtbox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Hmm looks better in the way you put it. But any "side-effects" if I use nested event handling? I guess it's just more or less a bit confusing.

Comment: No side-effects, you're just calling a method like any other really.

Answer (score 1):

An event handler is nothing more than a method, so you can call it like any other.